# How to fix TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PngImageFile in python

Tags: python, image, bounds

Please find below code

def get_document_bounds(image, feature):
    # [START vision_document_text_tutorial_detect_bounds]
    """Returns document bounds given an image."""
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=r'C:\DSpython\bounds.json'
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

```
bounds = []

with io.open(image, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image= types.Image(content=content)

response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
document = response.full_text_annotation

# Collect specified feature bounds by enumerating all document features
for page in document.pages:
    for block in page.blocks:
        for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
            for word in paragraph.words:
                for symbol in word.symbols:
                    if (feature == FeatureType.SYMBOL):
                        bounds.append(symbol.bounding_box)

                if (feature == FeatureType.WORD):
                    bounds.append(word.bounding_box)

            if (feature == FeatureType.PARA):
                bounds.append(paragraph.bounding_box)

        if (feature == FeatureType.BLOCK):
            bounds.append(block.bounding_box)

# The list `bounds` contains the coordinates of the bounding boxes.
# [END vision_document_text_tutorial_detect_bounds]
return bounds
```

***my objective is need to extract text from image. As part of that i am creating boundaries in this function "get document _bounds" .

"with io.open(image, 'rb') as image_file:" while open the image using io.open function i am getting above code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put

```
image= types.Image(content=content)
```

BEFORE

```
with io.open(image, 'rb') as image_file:
content = image_file.read()
```

?

Comment: While executing above code i am getting above error.the above not able to read PngImage file.

Comment: do you have a content variable declared before you open the file? What is the type and printout of content after you open the file? Are you sure the image file/path is valid? Can you open it in an external viewer?